BigQuery IAM- can I do insert only?
I'm trying to configure IAM permissions for a data ingestion pipeline.
Unfortunately, as best as I can tell, the ingest IAM key will need updateData on the table. This would allow a truncate/update statement.
Is there a way to restrict this key's permissions to just insert only?

This question is similar to: Bigquery - write only authorization. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
